# Profile into spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, profile

I have a question about spring security and it´s regarding to:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
```

I need that user´s name can make some operations that it´s not same to other operations for other user, that is,

```
User Admin can make: create, read, delete, update.
User A can make: create, read, update.
User B can make: read, delete.
```

Each user is a different profile with different operations.

Can I make with spring-security?
In database is similar to:
[image]

Both users go to same pages but with different oprations, for example, www.myApp.com/pageOperation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security, permission for some action invoking is stored as GrantedAuthority object within current [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object in "authorities" collection 
So, you should provide different authorities collection for different users by checking user name. You can hardcode them into `<user-service>` section or provide own implementation of  [UserDetailService](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html), which resolve user authorities basing on user name. `UserDetailsService` has method [loadUserByUsername](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29) which acepts username and returns [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) entity which contains user authorities collection. You can check user authority while he invoking some action by applying `@PreAuthorize` annotation to target method or by interception appropriate url. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a global vision about you tell it to me, but I don´t make an idea like it would be. Do you know any example where it is explained this? It´s for I see it better